# Class destruction segfault

Tags: c++, class, pointers, segmentation-fault

*This post is not a duplicate.  Read my question first.*

I'm certainly missing something here.  I would like to have my `Entity` class be able to destroy an instance of itself when the health quantity is zero.

```
    virtual int takeDamage(int damage)  {
    health -= damage;
    if(health <= 0) delete this;
}
```

What's wrong with the above code?  The program crashes with a segfault when the last line above is called.
So far I have tried:

- Making a custom destructor
- Making a destructor function:

  virtual void destroy(Entity*e)  {
    delete e;
  }
- Destroying the object where it was allocated

I removed the last line of `takeDamage()` and then called `delete object` from `main`.

```
if(tris[i]->getHealth() <=0) delete tris[i]; //called from the main function where a temporary collision detection occurs over all the entities in the program
```

I've located some of the issue, and it comes down to the following.  The instances of all the `Entity`(s) in my program (of one particular specialization, ie: Triangles) are stored in a `vector`.  For example, the above code uses this vector: `vector<Triangle*> tris;` (`Triangle` inherits `Entity`).  Then, that vector is iterated through and various operations are performed, such as collision detection, AI, etc. Now, when one of the objects is deleted, the next time we have iterated through the entire vector, we come to the object which has been deleted.  The next question is, what would I do to shrink that vector? (Now *this* is a good place to flag the question is perhaps needing of a separate question!)

Comment: Deleting an object that other code might use later, will result in error.

Comment: `The next question is, what would I do to shrink that vector?` Are you looking for `vector::erase`, by any chance?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes! That is indeed what I am looking for! I found the documentation on that just moments ago, I'll be sure to look into it and post back when I have a solution! Thank you!

Comment: What do you do after `takeDamage` returns, in the initial case? What happened when you moved the `delete` to `main`?

Comment: @AlanStokes after `takeDamage` the loop restarts. If `delete` is moved to main, the same problem occurs. The problem is that the loop does not remove items destroyed, and the next time around it performs operations on a deleted object, thus causing a segfault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your description, There is a way to do this safely using algorithm functions.  The algorithm functions you may be looking for are `std::stable_partition`, `for_each`, and `erase`.

Assume you have the "game loop", and you're testing for collisions during the loop:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
//...
std::vector<Entity*> allEntities;
//...
while (game_is_stlll_going())
{
    auto it = allEntities.begin();
    while (it != allEntitities.end())
    {
        int damage = 0;
        // ... assume that damage has a value now.
        //...
        // call the takeDamage() function
        it->takeDamage(damage);
        ++it;
    }

    // Now partition off the items that have no health
    auto damaged = std::stable_partition(allEntities.begin(),    
           allEntities.end(), [](Entity* e) { return e->health > 0; });

    // call "delete" on each item that has no health
    std::for_each(damaged, allEntities.end(), [] (Entity *e) { delete e; });

    // erase the non-health items from the vector.
    allEntities.erase(damaged, allEntities.end());

    // continue the game...
}
```

Basically what the loop does is that we go through all the entities and call `takeDamage` for each one.  We don't delete any entities at this stage.  When the loop is done, we check to see which items have no health by partitioning off the damaged items using the `std::stable_partition` algorithm function.

Why `stable_partition` and not just call `std::remove` or `std::remove_if` and before erasing the items, call `delete` on the removed items?  The reason is that with `remove / remove_if`, you cannot do a multi-step deletion process (call `delete` and then erase it from the vector).  The `remove/remove_if` algorithm functions assumes what has been moved to the end of the container (i.e. the "removed" items) are no longer needed and thus cannot be used for anything except for the final call to `vector::erase`.  Calling `delete` on removed items is undefined behavior.

So to solve this issue, you need to "partition off" the bad items first, deallocate the memory for each item, and *then* remove them.  We need to use a partitioning algorithm, so we have a choice of `std::stable_partition` or `std::partition`.  Which one?  We choose `std::stable_partition`.  The reason why we chose `std::stable_partition` over `std::partition` is to keep the relative order of the items intact.  The order of the items may be important for your game implementation.

Now we call `stable_partition` to partition the items into two sides of the entities vector -- the good items on the left of the partition, the bad items on the right of the partition.  The lambda function is used to decide which entity goes where by testing the `health` value.  The "partition" in this case is an iterator which is returned by `stable_partition`.

Given this, we call `for_each`, where the lambda calls `delete` on each item to the right of the partition, and then a `vector::erase()` to remove everything to the right of the partition.  Then we loop again, redoing this whole process until the game is finished.

Another thing you will notice is the safety of the code above.  If all entries have some health, then the calls to `stable_partition`, `for_each`, and `erase` are essentially no-ops.  So there is no need to explicitly check for at least one item having no health (but nothing stops you to from doing so, if you feel you need this micro-optimization).

And also, make sure your `Entity` base class has a `virtual destructor`, otherwise your code will exhibit undefined behavior on the delete.

Edit:  The `takeDamage()` function should be rewritten to *not* call `delete this`.

```
 virtual int takeDamage(int damage)  {
    health -= damage;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow.  That uses a lot of functions I had no idea were even in the standard library.  I did some research and I know what they do now, even if I don't understand how.  That said, research has also lead me to discover that a random-access operation on a vector is inefficient as compared to a `std::list`.  Is this true?  From what I can tell, the above code would still work, as the standard library is pretty well standardized. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: It won't let me edit the above comment... Regardless, I forgot to mention that `~Entity()` is declared as virtual, `virtual ~Entity(){}` and also default.

Comment: @PyroAVR - The code will work on `std::list`.  The algorithm functions use iterators.  If the iterator type for the container fits the algorithm, the algorithm will work.

Comment: great! I'll have to try that out as soon as possible, I have some restructuring to do as well...

Comment: You, sir, are a genius.  Thank you very much for the help!  I got this to work, and the explanation was great.